# Is there a way to make one code work for multiple buttons with the same functionallity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If i click right button, the left button shows up, and if I'm at the last page, the right button hides.
But now it happens for both sections, is it possible to make one code for them to count seperate ?

I made it possible with different id's but that's not really what i want. Because if I have more than 10 rows, it's hard code problem.

Is this possible with jquery ?

***HTML***

```html
<section>
  <div class="left" id="links"><div>
  <div class="right" id="rechts"><div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="left" id="btn-l"><div>
  <div class="right" id="btn-r"><div>
</section>
```

***CSS***

```
#links {
    text-align: center;
    width:50px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 145px;
    z-index: 100;
}
#rechts {
    text-align: center;
    width:50px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 145px;
    z-index: 100;
}
#btn-l {
    text-align: center;
    width:50px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 310px;
    z-index: 100;
}
#btn-r {
    text-align: center;
    width:50px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 315px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

***Jquery***

```
var page1 = 0;
$('.left').hide();
$('.right').click(function(){
  $('.left').show();
  page1+= 1;
  if(page1 >= 3) {
    $('.right').hide();
  }
});
$('.left').click(function(){
  page1-=1;
  if(page1<3){
    $('.right').show();
  }
  if(page1 == 0){
    $('.left').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your jQuery where you reference any element by an ID. If my answer doesn't match what you're looking for, could you explain what you need a little more?

Comment: bad html `<div class="left" id="links"><div>` must be `<div class="left" id="links"></div>` and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Like this:

```js
var buttons_count = 10;
  var page = 0;

  function show_buttons(){
    if(page==0){
     $('.left').hide();
    }else{
     $('.left').show();
    }
    if(page==buttons_count-2){
     $('.right').hide();
    }else{
     $('.right').show();
    }
   }

   $('.but').click(function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('left')){
     page--;
     }
     if($(this).hasClass('right')){
     page++;
     }
     $('#out').html('This page '+ (page+1) +' from '+ (buttons_count-1) ); /* for test only */
     show_buttons();
   });

    $('#out').html('This page '+ (page+1) +' from '+ (buttons_count-1) ); /* for test only */
    show_buttons();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <button class="but left">left</button>
  <button class="but right">right</button>

<div id="out"></div>

  <button class="but left">left</button>
  <button class="but right">right</button>
```

Variant two (for many divs):

```js
  function show_buttons(_el){
    var this_out = $(_el).parent().find('.out');
    var page = parseInt(this_out.attr('page'), 10);
    var cnt = parseInt(this_out.attr('cnt'), 10);



    if(page==0){
     $(_el).parent().find('.left').hide();
    }else{
     $(_el).parent().find('.left').show();
    }
    if(page==cnt-2){
     $(_el).parent().find('.right').hide();
    }else{
     $(_el).parent().find('.right').show();
    }

    this_out.html('This page '+ (page+1) +' from '+ (cnt-1) );
   }

   $('.but').click(function(){
     var this_out = $(this).parent().find('.out');
     var page = parseInt(this_out.attr('page'), 10);
     var cnt = parseInt(this_out.attr('cnt'), 10);


     if($(this).hasClass('left')){
     page--;
     }
     if($(this).hasClass('right')){
     page++;
     }
     this_out.attr('page', page);
     show_buttons(this);
   });

   $('.out').each(function(){
       show_buttons(this);
   });
```

```css
  span{
   width:200px;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:1px;
   display:inline-block;
  }
  </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <span>
   <button class="but left">left</button>
   <button class="but right">right</button>
   <div page="0" cnt="10" class="out"></div>
   <button class="but left">left</button>
   <button class="but right">right</button>
 </span>
 <span>
   <button class="but left">left</button>
   <button class="but right">right</button>
   <div page="3" cnt="8" class="out"></div>
   <button class="but left">left</button>
   <button class="but right">right</button>
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the function i need but for multiple left and right buttons in different sectors

Comment: Added an extra pair of buttons

Answer (score 1):

You can also try -

```
<div onclick="myFunction(this)">Left</div>
<div onclick="myFunction(this)">Right</div>
<script>
function myFunction(elmnt) {
  //Show hide elements as you want
}
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, i see what you mean, but what if I have multiple left and right buttons, Then I will need to make 2 counts for each sector ?

Comment: The 1990's called and want their `onclick=` back

Answer (score 1):

I think you need learn about javascript object, for a start..

```js
// javascript object information about page..
const movin = [ { pageMax: 10, page: 3, ID_left: 'links', ID_Right: 'rechts'  }
              , { pageMax: 7,  page: 2, ID_left: 'btn-l', ID_Right: 'btn-r'  }
              ];

$('.left, .right').click(function()
  {
  let ref
    , elmID = $(this).attr('id')
    ;
  if ($(this).hasClass('right'))
    {
    ref = movin.findIndex(e=>e.ID_Right === elmID );
    movin[ref].page++;
    }
  else
    {
    ref = movin.findIndex(e=>e.ID_left === elmID );
    movin[ref].page--;
    }

  console.clear();
  console.log('page=', movin[ref].page ,'/',  movin[ref].pageMax );

  $('#'+movin[ref].ID_left).css('visibility', (movin[ref].page===0)?'hidden':'visible' );
  $('#'+movin[ref].ID_Right).css('visibility', (movin[ref].page===movin[ref].pageMax)?'hidden':'visible' );
  })
```

```css
div { display: inline-block; padding: .3em .7em; border: 1px solid grey; margin: 1em; cursor: pointer;}
div:hover { background-color: coral; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="left" id="links"> left 1</div>
  <div class="right" id="rechts">right 1</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="left" id="btn-l"> left 2</div>
  <div class="right" id="btn-r"> right 2 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is to obtain a reference to the relevant div within the same section, you can do this within the event handler with:

```
var section = $(this).closest("section");
```

the left/right buttons can then be found within this, eg:

```
var left = section.find(".left");
```

then use `left` rather than `$(".left")` and it will be the related "button" within that section.

Example snippet using this concept:

```js
var maxPage = 3;

$(".left").click(function() {
  var section = $(this).closest("section");
  var page = section.find(".page").text() * 1;
  page--;
  if (page < 1)
    page = 1;
  section.find(".page").text(page);
  $(this).attr("disabled", page == 1);
  section.find(".right").attr("disabled", false);
});

$(".right").click(function() {
  var section = $(this).closest("section");
  var page = section.find(".page").text() * 1;
  page++;
  if (page > maxPage)
    page = maxPage;
  section.find(".page").text(page);
  $(this).attr("disabled", page == maxPage);
  section.find(".left").attr("disabled", false);
});

$(".left").attr("disabled", true);
```

```css
.left,
.right {
  border: 1px solid green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left[disabled],
.right[disabled] {
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  /*pointer-events:none;*/
}

section {
  clear: both;
}

section>div {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

section+section {
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class='page'>1</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class='page'>1</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</section>
```

There's still some duplication, eg changing the page and setting the enabled disabled - these can easily enough be combined, but the *first* step is to combine multiple left button clicks into a single function and multiple right button clicks into a single (separate) function.

---

As a side note, you would be better served using

```
<button type='button class'left'>left</button>
```

rather than a `<div>` as it will handle clicks better (especially double clicks rather than selecting the text)

Answer (score 0):

Give the buttons a common class, and attach a single click function to that class once the page has loaded, like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".alertButton").click(function(){
  alert("clicked!");
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="alertButton">Click me 1</button>
<button class="alertButton">Click me 2</button>
<button class="alertButton">Click me 3</button>
<button class="alertButton">Click me 4</button>
<button class="alertButton">Click me 5</button>
<button class="alertButton">Click me 6</button>
<button class="alertButton">Click me 7</button>
<button class="alertButton">Click me 8</button>
<button class="alertButton">Click me 9</button>
<button class="alertButton">Click me 10</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pages = {s1:0,s2:0};
$('.left').hide();
$('.right').click(function(){
  var sectionId = $(this).parents('section').attr('id');

  $('.left').show();
  pages[sectionId] = pages[sectionId]+1;
  if(pages[sectionId] >= 3) {
    $('#'+ sectionId +' .right').hide();
  }
});
$('.left').click(function(){
var sectionId = $(this).parents('section').attr('id');
  pages[sectionId] = pages[sectionId]-1;
  if(pages[sectionId]<3){
    $('#'+ sectionId +' .right').show();
  }
  if(pages[sectionId] == 0){
    $('#'+ sectionId +' .left').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<section id="s1">
  <div class="left"><div>
  <div class="right"><div>
</section>
<section id="s2">
  <div class="left"><div>
  <div class="right"><div>
</section>
```